# WebVR - How to display on the headset screen AND a monitor screen

Tags: three.js, oculus, webvr

I am displaying a WebVR scene in a browser.
But only the user with the headset (an oculus rift) can see the scene.

My question :
**Is there a way to see on another screen what the user see ?**
I would like to give advices to the user (you can do that, you can go here too, etc).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/) which can capture external monitors (like the Rift in extended mode) and individual windows. It's typically used for recording and streaming but you can use it for mirroring with its "Preview" mode. This works pretty well usually, although it does take some time to setup correctly and can be temperamental.

There are a couple of reddit posts about setup tips:

- "Guide: Mirroring Rift display using OBS" by hargabyte: https://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/2d1ujo/guide_mirroring_rift_display_using_obs
- "My recording settings for DK2 apps using OBS" by eVRydayVR: https://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/2gerrj/my_recording_settings_for_dk2_apps_using_obs/